# Binding two Linq queries from different tables and displaying them in one view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the combinesearch action which combines two Linq query and sends to the view. Also, I have the model which defines two existed table that I am trying to display all data together. The only problem is the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'JobsOfferSystem.Models.Combined', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[JobsOfferSystem.Models.Combined]'.
```

Action

```
 public ActionResult CombineSearch()
    {
        var result1 = db.Job.Where(m=>m.JobTitle.Contains("Developer")).ToList();
        var result2 = db.ReedApiModel.Where(m => m.jobTitle.Contains("Developer")).ToList();
        var model = new Combined()
        {
            Job =    result1,
            ReedApiModel = result2
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model

```
public class Combined
{
    public List<Job> Job { get; set; }
    public List<ReedApiModel> ReedApiModel { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
 @model IEnumerable<JobsOfferSystem.Models.Combined>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CombineSearch";
}

<h2>CombineSearch</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Job Model:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public string JobImage { get; set; }
    public string UniqueJobImageName { get; set; }
    //The current user publishing a job
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's obvious. Your view expects a set (multiple elements) of type `Combined` but what you pass is a single element of that type. Correct either the model you pass or the view.

Comment: How can I do this since that only one model is allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need to do is to create an empty View and than add the code manually to it.

also you need to add the following line to the view:

```
@model JobsOfferSystem.Models.Combined
```

instead of:

```
@model IEnumerable<JobsOfferSystem.Models.Combined>
```

and in the model you can do something like:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Job> Job { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ReedApiModel> ReedApiModel { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
List<Combined> model= result1.Concat(result2);
```

or

```
List<Combined> newList = new List<myClass>();
newList.AddRange(result1);
newList.AddRange(result2);
return View(newList.AsEnumerable())
```

Comment: what I get is this list does not contain a definition for `concat`

Comment: add the complete code of the view...for better understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205812/discussion-between-ghassa-and-ishwar-gagare).